# HTTP connection pool utilization check

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, httpconnection

In my spring-boot 2.1 app I have set up PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with 100 connections max.

Is there a way to know how many HTTP connections are utilized in HTTP connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager  implements org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl that has getStats and getTotalStats methods. Use them.